# Has a PHP update given me a 404?

Tags: php, wp-admin, 404-error

I have just changed hosting to Hostgator and installed wordpress to site Renuon.com.au

I had to update PHP, which I did to ea-php74.

The site loads the welcome Wordpress site but when I go to wp/admin it just says 404... How can I remedy this?

Any (simplistic!) help greatly received!

Comment: is wp/admin the real url? do you mean "domain.com/wp-admin"

Comment: Can you try /wp-admin/index.php i.e. add the index.php yourself? That exists as a file on disk and so should work even if some of your server settings e.g. default document index.php were lost.